# How can I control two events at once?

Tags: tiles, maps, rpg, events, rpg-maker-mv

I am trying to make a doorway that is 2 tiles high.
I have created an item called, `Door Key`. But I want both event tiles To hide or remove when I use the `Door Key`. The problem is I have to create two events to cover the doorway but can only get 1 event to change. So is there a way to change 2 events at once?

Comment: any plugins that could do this would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent the door with a single event, because an event graphic isn't constrained to be 1 x 1 tile. Examples of larger event graphics can be found in the files !Crystal, !Other2, !$Gate1, !$Gate2, $BigMonster1, and $BigMonster2 in the menu displayed when you double click the image panel in the event editor.

For a door 1 tile wide and 2 tiles high, you would need to create an image 144 pixels wide and 384 pixels high - four rows of three 48 x 96 pixel animation frames - and the file name will need to start with at least a $ (to indicate that it contains only the four rows of three animation frames for single event graphic instead of eight rows of twelve animation frames divided into eight (four by two) blocks of four rows of three frames for eight event graphics) and probably a ! before that (to indicate that it shouldn't be displaced upward by a few pixels).

When you select a large image for an event, don't let yourself be misled by the map editor cropping the image to the dimensions of a single tile. The whole image will be visible when you play the game.

Comment: its kinda helpful but its not really what im asking but still useful so I Voted it up.

Answer (score 2):

If there are other reasons why the door needs to be represented with two events, in addition to it needing a 1 x 2 tile graphic, the event code can set a movement route for both events and wait for neither of them to complete - the animations for both events will play simultaneously.

Assuming that the graphics for both parts of the door are typical door graphics where the down facing frames represent the closed door, the left facing frames represent the nearly closed door, the right facing frames represent the nearly open door, and the up facing frames represent the open door, the event code to open both sections of the door simultaneously could look like this:

```
Set Movement Route : Door Lower
                   : Turn Left
                   : Wait : 5 frames
                   : Turn Right
                   : Wait : 5 frames
                   : Turn Up
                   : Through ON
Set Movement Route : Door Upper
                   : Turn Left
                   : Wait : 5 frames
                   : Turn Right
                   : Wait : 5 frames
                   : Turn Up
                   : Through ON
```

When editing the Set Movement Route commands, remember to uncheck "Wait for Completion" - it's checked by default, and if you leave it checked, the first line of your Set Movement Route command will look like:

```
Set Movement Route : Door Lower (Wait)
```

instead of:

```
Set Movement Route: Door Lower
```

and the animation for the second event won't start until the animation for the first one has completed.